# Send data to server and server execute the query but no response in android device becasue of no internet connection

Tags: android, json, request, response

I am sending a json data to server, Now while I have sent the data and waiting for server response, suddenly my android device gets internet connection lost.So what  showing an alert dialog of connection lost, but at server side the data was already processed and updated in database and query executed But my android phone does not know this as it did not get response ever. How to resolve it.

Comment: From API side at last you fetch Response Message. Response Message success or fail ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely just on server confirmation "yes, done". Regardless of confirmation, next time you perform some action on device first ask server and analyze real server's data regarding the action. Many can happen , server's DB crashed and rolled back, and so on.

Comment: this i  need real time as user is placing some  order and need instant response from server, on that response need to show particular screen

Comment: As connection is lost, there is no more real time. It's loosely coupled system, and it should not pretend it's not. On that particular screen you need real server data I guess, not those inferred from the hope that all is OK.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving data from the server send an acknowledgment from client to server telling that response received successfully,then update what ever thins you need on the server side.